# Sorting Wordpress Posts Timestamp

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, timestamp

I have a custom post type of events. I want to display the event only if its today or upcoming.

The problem i'm having is if I have multiple events, the order isnt going according to the date.

I did try echoing the timestamp and it was off - it needs to be converted to php timestamp - is there a way to divide the timestamp by 1000 in jquery before it saves it? or am I totally off here

any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Custom field**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" size="30" />
<input type="hidden" id="event_date" size="30" />
```

**datepicker js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'DD, MM dd',
            altField: "#event_date",
        altFormat: '@'
        });
});
```

**Callback php**

```
<?php $classarg = array('post_type' => 'class', 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'event_date', 'value' => time(), 'compare' => '>=',),),'orderby'=> 'key', 'posts_per_page'=> '-1', 'order'=>'ASC');
$classes = new WP_Query($classarg ); if ( $classes->have_posts() ) {while ( $classes->have_posts() ) { $classes->the_post();?>

<h2><?php the_title();?></h2>

<?php the_content();?>

<?php }} wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was missing `meta_key` parameter and `orderby` has to be `meta_value_num`

So this works now

```
 <?php
    $classarg= array(
        'post_type' => 'class',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'event_date', 'value' => time(), 'compare' => '>=',),),
        'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $classes = new WP_Query($classarg  ); 
    if ( $classes->have_posts() ): while ( $classes->have_posts() ) : $classes->the_post();?>

    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>

    <?php the_content();?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```